# How to report any and all exceptions to Bugsnag from Laravel 5.2 app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bugsnag

Having installed Laravel and Bugsnag using the relevant documentation, I found that an `NotFoundHttpException` error for instance is not reported to Bugsnag (but `notifyError` yes). My question is how to set it so that *all* errors are reported, without using these lines over and over:

```
Bugsnag::notifyError('ErrorType', 'Something bad happened');
```

or

```
try {
    // Some potentially crashy code
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    Bugsnag::notifyException($ex);
}
```

I'm thinking of using the `Handler` in `app/exceptions` like so:

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    Bugsnag::notifyException($e);
    parent::report($e);
}
```

But if it's not mentioned in the Laravel/Bugsnag integration docs, is it a good practice? This [Laracast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4gK5uynk2s) doesn't describe any changes to the exceptions handler and the setup seems to work as intended.

Comment: We put ours in the Handler, works well.

Answer (score 3):

In App\Exceptions\Handler, remove all Exception classes from $dontReport.  I'm not sure why you'd want to report all errors, but this should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In

> \app\Exceptions\Handler.php

overwrite  `internalDontReport` property.
Below is a default that comes inherited from `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
protected $internalDontReport = [
    AuthenticationException::class,
    AuthorizationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    HttpResponseException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    TokenMismatchException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
];
```